# Getting the SQL from a Rails Migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Does anyone know of a way to see the SQL that would be generated by a migration (preferably without actually running the migration)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this pulugin: http://github.com/muness/migration_sql_generator/tree/master